# IdentityServer - Using Hybrid Flow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3

I implemented an IdentityServer3 and try to use it with my new ASP.NET Core MVC application.

I want to use the Hybrid Flow but I don't seem to get it working.

My client on the IdentityServer3 is setup like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientName = "Test",
    ClientId = "Test",
    ClientUri = "http://localhost:59528/",
    Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
    AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
    {
        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        Constants.StandardScopes.Profile
    },
    RedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc",
    },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
    {
        "http://localhost:59528/",
    },
    Enabled = true
}
```

ASP.NET Core MVC application it is setup like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfigurationService configurationService, ApplicationDbContextSeedData seeder)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    /* Logging Configuration */
    loggerFactory.AddConsole();
    if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Error);
    }

    /* Identity Server Configuration */
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true
    });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(configurationService.GetOpenIdConnectOptions());

    /* MVC Route Configuration */
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);

    /* Database Configuration */
    seeder.EnsureSeedData().Wait();
}
```

Here are the options that I read in the *GetOpenIdConnectOption* method:

```
"OpenIdConnectOptions": {
    "AuthenticationScheme": "oidc",
    "SignInScheme": "Cookies",
    "Authority": "http://localhost:7506/",
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": "false",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:59528/",
    "ClientId": "Test",
    "ResponseType": "code id_token token",
    "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": "true",
    "SaveTokens": "true",
    "Scopes": [ "openid", "profile" ]
}
```

With this setup I get redirected to the IdentityServer, I can login and after I allow my application I get redirected to an error page on my  ASP.NET Core MVC application with the following error:

```
http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc
HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

If I change some settings (add ClientSecret to Server and Client and change the flow) I managed to get it working with the Implicit Flow but I would prefer the Hybrid flow.

Does somebody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** 
I changed some things (added secrets to client and server) and now I get the following log from the IdentityServer3. It seems everything is okay there.

```
2016-08-29 06:49:44,791 [18] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController Resuming from consent, restarting validation
2016-08-29 06:49:44,792 [18] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator Start authorize request protocol validation
2016-08-29 06:49:44,805 [25] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator Authorize request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "Test",
  "ClientName": "Test",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "...",
  "ResponseType": "code id_token token",
  "ResponseMode": "form_post",
  "Flow": "Hybrid",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email",
  "State": "...",
  "Nonce": "...",
  "SessionId": "...",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "Test",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "code token id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile email",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "...",
    "state": "..."
    }
}
2016-08-29 06:49:44,808 [20] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator Creating Hybrid Flow response.
2016-08-29 06:49:44,812 [15] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeResponseGenerator Creating Implicit Flow response.
2016-08-29 06:49:44,813 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating access token
2016-08-29 06:49:44,814 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating JWT access token
2016-08-29 06:49:44,865 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating identity token
2016-08-29 06:49:44,866 [15] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultClaimsProvider Getting claims for identity token for subject: 88010bab-091e-4095-8f5d-ac89a3fd9198
2016-08-29 06:49:44,920 [10] INFO  IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.TokenCleanup Clearing tokens
2016-08-29 06:49:44,983 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating JWT identity token
2016-08-29 06:49:45,035 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpointController Adding client virtualmoney to client list cookie for subject 88010bab-091e-4095-8f5d-ac89a3fd9198
2016-08-29 06:49:45,037 [15] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Results.AuthorizeFormPostResult Posting to http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc
2016-08-29 06:49:45,038 [15] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Results.AuthorizeFormPostResult Using DefaultViewService to render authorization response HTML
2016-08-29 06:49:45,179 [18] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController Start token request
2016-08-29 06:49:45,180 [18] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator Start client validation
2016-08-29 06:49:45,181 [18] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.BasicAuthenticationSecretParser Start parsing Basic Authentication secret
2016-08-29 06:49:45,182 [18] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.PostBodySecretParser Start parsing for secret in post body
2016-08-29 06:49:45,183 [18] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser Parser found secret: PostBodySecretParser
2016-08-29 06:49:45,184 [18] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretParser Secret id found: virtualmoney
2016-08-29 06:49:45,188 [24] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.SecretValidator Secret validator success: HashedSharedSecretValidator
2016-08-29 06:49:45,189 [24] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ClientSecretValidator Client validation success
2016-08-29 06:49:45,190 [24] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator Start token request validation
2016-08-29 06:49:45,191 [24] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator Start validation of authorization code token request
2016-08-29 06:49:45,218 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator Validation of authorization code token request success
2016-08-29 06:49:45,220 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.TokenRequestValidator Token request validation success
 {
  "ClientId": "Test",
  "ClientName": "Test",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "AuthorizationCode": "...",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "Test",
    "client_secret": "******",
    "code": "...",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc"
  }
}
2016-08-29 06:49:45,221 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator Creating token response
2016-08-29 06:49:45,223 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator Processing authorization code request
2016-08-29 06:49:45,225 [22] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating access token
2016-08-29 06:49:45,227 [22] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating JWT access token
2016-08-29 06:49:45,300 [22] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating identity token
2016-08-29 06:49:45,302 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultClaimsProvider Getting claims for identity token for subject: 88010bab-091e-4095-8f5d-ac89a3fd9198
2016-08-29 06:49:45,405 [22] DEBUG IdentityServer3.Core.Services.Default.DefaultTokenService Creating JWT identity token
2016-08-29 06:49:45,486 [22] INFO  IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointController End token request
```

But now I get this error on my client after the redirect from the IdentityServer3:

```
OpenIdConnectProtocolException: IDX10300: The hash claim: '...' in the id_token did not validate with against
```

Comment: You are not supplying the `RedirectUri`= http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc  of the `OpenIdConnectOptions`. What happens if you do?

Comment: I use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.OpenIdConnectOptions" from ASP.NET Core and sadly it doesn't have the Property "RedirectUri".

Comment: Is `ClientId` case sensitive? One is `Test` and the other is `test`.

Comment: I changed it and it is still not working, so it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: How are you getting redirected back to http://localhost:59528/signin-oidc, if you're never supplying it anywhere?

Comment: I think they've just renamed it to `CallbackPath` and made it relative.

https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Builder/RemoteAuthenticationOptions/index.html#prop-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RemoteAuthenticationOptions.CallbackPath

Comment: Ah, you're by chance using the default value they're using.

https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/6cd46a5c10094ba9f4379fbccc3b9c05a01bf034/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L52

Comment: Enable logging in identityserver. Everything is guessing (and a waste of time).

Comment: @leastprivilege I added my latest log but I'm not sure if it is helpful because there doesn't seem to be an error on the IdentityServer side.